# lucene highlighter: how can I get locations of fragments?

Tags: lucene, highlighting, fragment

I know how to get relevant highlighted fragments together with some surrounding text using Lucene highlighter, namely, using

```
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(scorer);
String[] fragments = highlighter.getBestFragments(stream, fieldContents, fragmentNumber);
```

But can I instead get pointers to these fragments in the original contents? In other words, I need to know where these fragments start and, if possible, end.

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549589/highlighting-whole-sentence-in-lucene-net-2-9-2

Comment: Not sure whether it will help but thanks for the pointer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `GetBestTextFragments` method instead, you will get back an array of `TextFragment`s. These have properties `textStartPos` and `textEndPos`.

(They are marked internal in Lucene.NET, which will require you to make some code changes to get access to them. I'm not sure about Java Lucene.)

Comment: Thanks. Java Lucene 3.4.0 has a `GetBestTextFragments` method that returns `TextFragment[]` but `TextFragment` does not give access to any position information. It seems it did in earlier versions of Lucene -- not sure why this changed.